# Extract zip file and concatenate the extracted content

Tags: powershell

I have multiple zip files which I want to unzip and concatenate its content to a single file. I do not need each of these unzipped files thus prefer that they never get created if possible.

I need to do this in powershell and only have access to version 2.0.

Currently using 7zip to perform the unzipping. If I do the unzip without attempting to concatenate the output, I end up with all the extracted files using following command.

```
# all the zip files (10000 of them)
$logs = Get-ChildItem $folders[$i] -filter "*$stake).zip" 

foreach ($log in $logs) {
    Write-Host $log
    & '7z' e $log
}
```

Attempting to concatenate all the files via following command but I still end up with all the extracted files and the combined.txt file contains repetition of following text. Please advice. Thanks.

```
# all the zip files (10000 of them)
$logs = Get-ChildItem $folders[$i] -filter "*$stake).zip" 

foreach ($log in $logs) {
    Write-Host $log
    & '7z' e $log >> combined.txt
}
```

Text being repeated

> 7-Zip [64] 16.04 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-10-04
>
> Scanning the drive for archives: 1 file, 7796 bytes (8 KiB)
>
> Extracting archive: 0000_0000_0000 Game Log (name at 86% staking
>   25).zip
>   -- Path = 0000_0000_0000 Game Log (name at 86% staking 25).zip Type = zip Physical Size = 7796

Further clarifications:

I have 10000 zip files.
Upon extraction, each file content = "Hello".

I want to concatenate all these file contents into 1 single file.

Thus single file content will be -

```
"Hello" 
"Hello" 
"Hello" 
... 10000 times
```

All I want is this single file which has the concatenated data.

Comment: When you say concatenate, do you mean there is a file in each of the ZIP archives that you want to merge into one file? Or do you just want them saved in the same folder? Or not extract them at all, just list the contents?

Comment: @Deadly-Bagel there is a file in each zip. I do not want to extract them at all if possible, just get the content, concatenate all contents into 1 single file.

Comment: Repeating yourself will not improve understanding. Your example has you extracting the files, which you then say you don't want (but it's literally all it does). Then you say you try to concatenate the output, but then list the output as "text being repeated". That is the output, not sure what you're expecting. Then you want to concatenate the "contents", which I can only assume is the contents of the actual files but you've not given us any detail on what they actually are. From your "text being repeated", the ZIP files contain another ZIP file?? Show us what you're expecting to get.

Comment: @Deadly-Bagel Not entirely sure about your confusion. I have added further clarifications above if that helps.

Comment: Ok, that clears it up, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK ZIP files need to be extracted before they can be read. Even in the case of ZIP browsers, when you "open" a file in it the file is extracted to a temporary location first.

So that's basically what you need to be doing:

```
$logs = Get-ChildItem $folders[$i] -filter "*$stake).zip"
New-Item -Name "Temp" -ItemType Directory
$output = @()

foreach ($log in $logs) {
    Write-Host $log
    & '7z' e $log -o"Temp" | Out-Null
    Get-ChildItem "Temp" | Foreach-Object {
        $output += Get-Content $_.FullName
        Remove-Item $_
    }
}

Remove-Item "Temp"

$output | Out-File "FullLog.txt"
```

This goes through each file, extracts it (ignores output of 7zip as it's informational only), reads the content of the extracted file then deletes it. Afterwards it cleans up and writes the total output to a file.

Comment: Shouldn't your `Get-ChildItem "Temp" | Foreach-Object` be outside the `foreach ($log in $logs)`? Currently you're getting every files content everytime a zip is extracted, so you'll have each file multiple times?

Comment: No... What if there are duplicate file names? It extracts one ZIP file, gets the contents of the extracted file(s) and adds it to $output, then deletes the file and moves on to the next. Sure, you probably could extract every single file -then- read them all and merge them but functionally there is little difference, other than that this way handles duplicate filenames should they exist.

Comment: Oh, I missed the `Remove-Item $_` doh!